# Busca de dados em um log

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problemas para enxergar onde está o meu erro, e também compreender e **arrumar** a demora da `query`.

Eu tenho uma função em `PHP` que faz o `parser` de um log gerado pelo `OpenVpn`. Abaixo deixarei algumas linhas desse log para vocês me ajudarem.

```
CLIENT_LIST cliente1    120.203.57.20:56256 120.203.57.20   172756  170025  Wed May 25 08:26:39 2016    1464175599  UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST cliente2    120.203.57.20:53266 120.203.57.20   339724  293760  Wed May 25 08:56:44 2016    1464177404  UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST cliente3    120.203.57.20:49751 120.203.57.20   1083595 945154  Tue May 24 21:36:21 2016    1464136581  UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST cliente3    120.203.57.20:55161 120.203.57.20   188704  187305  Wed May 25 07:57:48 2016    1464173868  UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST cliente4    120.203.57.20:1031  120.203.57.20   529298  521955  Wed May 25 06:30:38 2016    1464168638  UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST cliente5    120.203.57.20:30721 120.203.57.20   1208231 1049827 Tue May 24 14:37:04 2016    1464111424  UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST cliente6    120.203.57.20:63653 120.203.57.20   413439  363969  Wed May 25 07:57:25 2016    1464173845  UNDEF
```

A função que analisa cada linha desse log e armazena em uma tabela no banco de dados:

```
$log = "log.log";

ovpnParser($log, $con);

function ovpnParser($log, $con)
{
  echo '<script>console.log("testing...")</script>';
  $inclients = false;
  $handle = fopen($log, "r");

  $inclients = false;
  while (!feof($handle))
  {
    $line = fgets($handle, 4096);

    if (substr($line, 0, 11) == "CLIENT_LIST")
    {
      if (preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST\t{1,}UNDEF(.*)UNDEF/", $line))
      {
        $inclients = false;
        echo '<script>console.log("client is not on the list...")</script>';
      }
      else
      {
        $inclients = true;
        echo '<script>console.log("client is in the list...")</script>';
      }
    }

    if ($inclients)
    {
      preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST(.*)UNDEF/", $line, $conteudo);

      $partes = preg_split("/\t{1,}/", trim($conteudo[1]));

      $sql            = "SELECT comName FROM vpn
                        WHERE  comName = '{$partes[0]}'";
      $query          =  mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      $numeroDeLinhas =  mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($numeroDeLinhas == 0)
    {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO vpn (comName, realAddr, virtAddr, byR, byS, since, sinstamp, blockstatus)
            VALUES ('{$partes[0]}', '{$partes[1]}', '{$partes[2]}', '{$partes[3]}', '{$partes[4]}', '{$partes[5]}', '{$partes[6]}', 'true')";

      $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      echo '<script>console.log("new client added to the list...")</script>';
    }
    elseif ($numeroDeLinhas > 0)
    {
      clientcmp($conexao, $partes[0]);
    }
  }
  $inclients = false;
}
echo '<script>console.log("the test is finished...")</script>';
```

}

Observação: eu coloquei alguns `echo` para que eu acompanhe exatamente em que parte o código esta sendo executado no momento.

Além de fazer este `parser` para poder inserir em uma tabela no banco de dados, eu preciso saber se o cliente está conectado ou não.

A lógica é assim: ao executar o `parser`, ele vai checar no banco se existe algum cliente com aquele nome, caso não exista, esse cliente é inserido no banco, e se o cliente está presente no log, quer dizer que ele está com a `vpn` conectada.

Agora a parte que não estou conseguindo fazer: se o cliente está no banco de dados mas ele não está nesse arquivo de log, isso quer dizer que ele está com a `vpn` desconectada!

Esse arquivo de log é atualizado a cada 1 minuto, ou seja, esse `parser` será executado a cada 1 minuto.

Na tabela no banco de dados, eu adicionei uma coluna "connectedOr", se estiver conectado, tenho que armazenar `true`, se ele não estiver conectado, tenho que armazenar `false`.

A função que eu havia feito pra essa finalidade, é essa:

```
function clientcmp($conexao)
{
  $start = microtime(true);
  $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
  $str1 = "kg-01239918000150"; // nome do log


  $x = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    $x = $row['comName'];
    if ($str1 == $x)
    { // está no log e está no banco de dados
      $sql = "UPDATE vpn SET connectedOr = 'true' WHERE comName = '{$x}'";
      $queryy = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
      echo '<script>console.log("cliente consta no log e consta no banco de dados.")</script>';
    }
    elseif ($str1 != $x)
    {
      $sql = "UPDATE vpn SET connectedOr = 'false' WHERE comName = '{$x}'";
      $queryy = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
      echo '<script>console.log("cliente não consta no log e consta no banco de dados.")</script>';
    }
  }
  $time_post = microtime(true);
  $exec_time = ($time_post - $start)/60;
  echo $exec_time;
}
```

**Da forma que fiz para saber se está conectado ou desconectado ele SEMPRE verifica o nome do cliente1, nunca indo para os outros clientes, já a inserção do banco de dados está funcionando corretamente.**

Obrigado!